# How to generate .rpt file in Azure Data studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-data-studio

I am new to SQL Server. I have a Mac so I can't use SSMS. I am using Azure Data Studio and Docker container to run SQL Server. But I am not able to generate `.rpt` files in Azure Data Studio. I have a `.sql` file for which I need to generate a `.rpt` file.

Is there any way to generate `.rpt` files in Azure Data Studio? We can do that in SSMS. If there is any other way to do that in mac I will try.

I tried searching Azure Data Studio documentation. Also searched Google. Also tried `sqlcmd` but was not able to run that.

Comment: Unless it has been added in the last year, Azure Data Studio does not have built-in support for generating .rpt files directly.   You have to do it yourself.  Lucky for you there are a few that work with Mac, I can't make a suggestion due to site rules.  But they are out there.

Comment: You've tagged both mysql and sql-server, but it sounds like your issue is confined to the SQL Server space.

Comment: @easleyfixed I'm pretty sure you're allowed to mention available tools in your comments (disclosing any ownership you may have in them). The restriction is on _asking questions_ which seek those recommendations.

Comment: Ah fair enough, that makes the most sense.  Well, if you do a search for report software for sql and mac, you will get plenty to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. We can use the sqlcmd and obcd tools and then run below cmd to create rpt file

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P <Password> -i /Users/LocationTOFile -o /Users/LocationTOOutputFile.rpt
```